# TableView adding newScore from firestore at top, even when it is not the highest score

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to put a leaderboard together. It works well, except whenever I create a new build of my app on my device, when a player adds their score to the database, there is no problem. However when the player then clicks to see the leaderboard. The results are all displayed in the correct order, however the players new score is placed on the top (even though it is not the highest score). The same score is then again seen in the correct position.

This only happens first time on a new build. If I go back and play it again The order is fine and the score is placed in the correct place only.

I have already tried adding a dummy score to the database when the user starts a new build to simulate a position on the leaderboard as a placement holder. But this then gets added to the top of the leaderboard as well as their new score (whether it is the highest or not).

```
var scoresArray = [ScoreClass]()

class ScoreClass {

    var name = ""
    var score = 0

    init(withName: String, andScore: Int) {
        name = withName
        score = andScore
    }
}
```

Adding the data to the database....

```
func addingScoreToFB() {
    let score = Int(self.recentScores.last ?? "")
    if score ?? 0 > Int(playerHighScore ?? "") ?? 0 { {
        if let username = usernameText {
            let newScore = TopScore(username: username, highScore: (score)!)
            var ref:DocumentReference? = nil
            ref = self.db.collection("users").addDocument(data: newScore.dictionary) {
                error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error adding document:\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        print("Document added with reference: \(ref!.documentID)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Retrieving the data

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()

func retrieveUserData() {

    let postsRef = self.db.collection("users")

    let query = postsRef
                    .order(by: "highScore", descending: true)
                    .limit(to: 50)

    query.addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in documentSnapshot!.documents {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    let dict = document.data()
                    let name = dict["username"] as! String
                    let score = dict["highScore"] as! Int
                    let aScore = ScoreClass(withName: name, andScore: score)
                    self.scoresArray.insert(aScore, at: 0)
                }

            self.topScoresTableView.reloadData()
            }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if there is anything wrong with the database retrieval, but I don't understand why that would only be affected on a fresh build on the first play. Any help provided will be much appreciated.

Edit: To include tableView display functionality & scoreObject

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = topScoresTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    let scoreClassObject = scoresArray.reversed()[row]
    let name = scoreClassObject.name
    let score = scoreClassObject.score
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.usernameLabel.text = name
    cell.resultLabel.text = String(score)
    cell.rankNumberLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
    print(scoresArray)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what order the scores should be in. You say *The results are all displayed in the correct order* but then *players new score is placed on the top* so it's then not the correct order? Is the actual issue the score is displaying twice? Also, you're inserting at index 0 (as mentioned in an answer). However, descending means 10, 9, 8... 0 and that's how the data will be presented by Firebase so if you're adding to an array with the highest score at the top, you want 10 and index 0, 9 at index 1, 8 at index 2 so inserting at index 0 will reverse that.

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clearer that yes the new score is being repeated twice. Once at the top (position no.1) and then again in its rightful place. I am reversing the order in which the data is shown in the tableView which I have now added. E.g if I have the points displaying 
(1.)100   (2.) 85   (3.)74. When a new build is created and a player plays (it doesn't matter if the player has played before or not), when the user adds visits the leaderboard (only for the first time), the new score is placed on top so this is how it looks. 
(1.)65   (2.)100   (3.)85   (4.)74   (5.)65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be fully understanding the question so this is a 'beta' answer which may need to be updated.

Looking at the code in the question, it appears the data that you want to display in descending order is having it's order changed several times, and that may not be necessary.

It's read in descending, but then it's ascending again because of how the elements are added to the array; .insert(aScore, at: 0). But as the tableView cells are being populated, the data being read is reversed again.

Let's assme there are 4 scores; 2, 3, 1, 0

And then the existing query to read them descending.

```
let query = postsRef
                .order(by: "highScore", descending: true)
                .limit(to: 50)
```

The Firestore closure will present the data in descending order so it can be added to the array

```
 self.scoresArray = [] //***start with an empty array, and clear it each time
 for document in documentSnapshot!.documents {
                    let dict = document.data()
                    let name = dict["username"] as! String
                    let score = dict["highScore"] as! Int
                    let aScore = ScoreClass(withName: name, andScore: score)
                    self.scoresArray.insert(aScore) //***NOTE THE CHANGE***
                }
```

The array will then contains the scores

```
[index 0] = 3
[index 1] = 2
[index 2] = 1
[index 3] = 0
```

Then to populate the cell for each row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = topScoresTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    let scoreObject = self.scoresArray[row] //***NOTE THE CHANGE***
    let score = scoreObject.score
    cell.resultLabel.text = String(score)
    return cell
}
```

Your tableview will then contain all the scores descending.

Note that the self.scoresRef = [] is needed because any time a new score document is added changed or removed, ALL of the scores will be reloaded so we need to clear the array and start fresh each time.

Comment: Where exactly should the self.scoresRef = [] be cleared, as when I am clearing it, the tableView shows nothing. Also should the scoresRef be the array that I insert aScore to? Thx

Comment: @rb2030 You've added a listener to the /users node which means when changes occur in that node, the code in the closure will be called. Keep in mind that as that code is called *all* of the nodes in /users is returned in the snapshot in descending order which would mean the array would be added to every time there was a change. To compensate for that, each time there's a change you would 'erase' the array and re-populate with the fresh data. Generally that would happen very quickly and the tableView will never appear 'empty'. So `self.scoresArray = []` would need to be done within the closure.

Comment: @rb2030 The other option is to have a higher degree of granularity and only update a single score as it changes, but then you are back to sorting in code. See [View Changes Between Snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots)

Comment: @rb2030 Oh and you asked about `self.scoresRef = []` - that should have been `self.scoresArray = []`. Just a typo and I have corrected that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Jay. You got it! just wondered, although the leaderboard works well now instead of clearing the array by putting self.scoresArray =[]
Should it be self.scoresArray = [ScoreClass]

As it is written when the array is instantiated, or is it only needed the once because on creation I already assigned what type of value was going to be in the array?

Comment: @rb2030 Arrays are smart and know what objects they contain, so = [] will work just fine. For some good additional reading, check out the official docs [Swift Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) in the Creating An Empty Array section.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting new entries at index 0, by doing this:

```
self.scoresArray.insert(aScore, at: 0)
```

You need to sort it here and insert it into proper place based on sorting you want to have.

Alternatively you can just run your `query` after adding new entry, to let Firebase do sorting for you on querying level.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough in my question. I have added more info, including the tableView displaying behaviour as to why it is put in position 0.